# About Robolectric.When I have object not init in an activity, how can I test that activity?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

When I write like this **MyActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);**

It always throw like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.printer.ui.activity.MyActivity.initView(MyActivity.java:309)
    at com.ui.activity.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:114)
```

That line is like this:

```
fileTextView.setText(AppUtil.getFileNameNoEx(AppConfig.printFile.getName()));
```

And **AppConfig.printFile** is null,how can I test that activity?

Comment: Can you share the code for `AppConfig`? When `printFile` is initiated?

Comment: Another Activity, it download a file  from internet, set value like this **AppConfig.printFile = new File(successFilePath)**, then it start MyActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So quick fix for your test do:

```
AppConfig.printFile = new File();
MyActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
```

The proper fix would be passing the path in activity intent:

```
public class MyActivity {
   public static final String FILE_PATH = "FILE_PATH";

   public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      super.onCreate(bundle);

      String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(FILE_PATH);
      ...
   } 
   ...
}

Intent myActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MyActivity.FILE_PATH, "path");
startActivity(intent);
```

Also try to avoid statics as much as possible http://www.endran.nl/blog/death-to-statics/

Comment: Thank you.Another question,can I init the AppConfig.printFile so it can be used in the whole test class, but not a single test.Is it possible?

Comment: You can extend test class or look to Roboelctric Test Application (http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/)